# Variable in overridden method does not existed in the parent class

Tags: java, overriding

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
  }

  public static class A {

    String f1 = "300";

    public A(){
      init();
    }

    protected void init(){}
  }

  public static class B extends A {

    private String f1 = "3";

    public B(){
      super();
      init();
    }

    protected void init(){
      System.out.println(f1);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
null
3
```

Can anyone explain to me the first line of the output? If I delete the line `String f1 = "300";`, it still has the same output also.

I have tried that if I declare some variables in `B` and invoke it in `init()` and all of it will be `null` in the constructor of `A`. In other words, my question is I want to know the reason for those variables being `null` at that point.

Comment: At the time `super()` is called from the `B` constructor, field `f1` in `B`, which is entirely separate from field `f1` in `A` (see [Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)), has not been assign yet, so it is null. Because `init()` is overridden, when `A` calls `init()`, it calls the `B` method, which then prints the (so far) uninitialized value.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Please help me with another question.
Why when A calls ```init()```, it does not invoke ```f1``` in ```A```?
Sorry if it is a no-point question.

Comment: I already told you: "Because `init()` is **overridden**, when `A` calls `init()`, it calls the `B` method". --- Seems you need to (re)read the section about [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in your Java learning guide, to learn about method overriding.

Comment: Because the assignment happens *after* the `super()` call. As I said: It hasn't been assigned **yet**.